# Spring MVC 3.0 form tag library - Any way to override the tag's name or id attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, taglib

I'm using the **form:select** taglib to generate a select with options.  Spring assigns the name and id attribute to the name of the path which I specify in the **form:select** declaration.  Is there any way to use a different name?

For example, the code:

```
  <form:select path="party.CustSalesTaxCategoryId" >
    <form:options items="${taxCodes}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="description" />
  </form:select>
```

Will generate:

```
<select id="CustSalesTaxCategoryId" name="CustSalesTaxCategoryId"
```

I would like to give it my own name.  If I add a name attribute to the form declaration, it will give the resulting tag 2 names, and the browser ignores the second name (mine).

Is there any way around this, or does it always have to be the same name as the path???

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need it? Field name should match the path for correct databinding.

Answer (score 1):

For the id, you can simply add it like in an HTML tag:

```
<form:select id="yourId" path="party.CustSalesTaxCategoryId" >
```

The name however is not a supported attribute, as the name is the very thing that allows spring to perform the binding of that request parameter to your command object.

You can however customize the binding if you really want to.